# BadImageFormatException on AppDomain Created Using AppDomain.CreateDomain

Tags: c#, appdomain, badimageformatexception

I am trying to track down the cause of a BadImageFormatException (Index not found.) exception.  The exception is thrown on line 2 of the following code:

```
AppDomain _trainingDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("TrainingDomain");
_trainingDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(AppDomain_UnhandledException);
_trainingDomain.SetData("RemoteDomain", AppDomain.CurrentDomain);
_trainingDomain.DoCallBack(InitializeRemoteDomain);
```

If I comment out the second line of code, the third line executes successfully and then the method fails again on the fourth line of code with the same exception.

This code is contained in a static method which is in the same static class containing both the AppDomain_UnhandledException and InitializeRemoteDomain methods.  All projects in the solution are compiled using with the x86 flag and .NET 4.5.1.  The application works properly on my development box (Windows 7 Pro x64) but is failing on the production box (Windows Embedded Standard x32).  I would think that the AppDomain I created using the CreateDomain method would have the same bitness as the existing AppDomain which was calling the CreateDomain method in the first place.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the issue was due to the version of .NET Reactor which we were using on our Build Servers to obfuscate code.